# Laravel foreach only returns first value

Tags: php, foreach, laravel, laravel-4, iteration

First please be gentle i am a beginner and only prectising,

I have a problem, i would like to get laravel's language files and edit their content.

My problem is what i dont really understand is the following

i have a functions what returns the actual files, i have a variable what stores this

```
$directory =  File::files(self::$lang_path.$code);
```

id i die and dump i get back the following

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(26) "app/lang/en/pagination.php"
  [1]=>
  string(25) "app/lang/en/reminders.php"
  [2]=>
  string(26) "app/lang/en/validation.php"
}
```

all fine, but if `foreach` it and die and dump

```
$directory =  File::files(self::$lang_path.$code);

    foreach ($directory as $files) 
    {
        dd($files);

    }
```

i just get back `string(26) "app/lang/en/pagination.php"`

could please tell me what i am doing wrong?

and the problem is i need it because i will need nested foreac

like

```
$directory =  File::files(self::$lang_path.$code);

        foreach ($directory as $files) 
        {
            foreach ($files as $file) 
            {
                // preform more stuff
            }

        }
```

and idont understand what iam doing wrong, could please someone give me a hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `dd` (dump and die) function kills script execution - It therefore will only show the first item in the array before calling `die()`.

Use `var_dump` instead.

If you're curious, you can see the [function definition here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php#L491).

Answer (score 0):

**Alternatively, you can use my helper function.**

```
function printPre($array, $string = false, $exit = true){

if(env('APP_ENV')=='local') {

    if($string){
        print_r($array, $string);
    }
    else{
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($array);
        echo '</pre>';
    }
    if($exit)
        exit;
}
```

}