# dd() within map function in Laravel only shows first object

Tags: php, laravel, dump, dd

Within a `map()` methid call, I would like to use `dd()` to dump but I only get the first object.
When I use `print_r()` within a map function I get all objects.

```
$valeurCategorieCible = $CategoriesItineraires->map(function ($item) {
    return $item->ciblesParCategorie->map(function ($ciblesParCategorie) {
        return $ciblesParCategorie->cibles->map(function ($items) {
                  print_r($items); // Return all objects
            dd($items); // Return only the first object then stop !
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Script execution / foreach() loop stops when I call Laravel's dd() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34428442/script-execution-foreach-loop-stops-when-i-call-laravels-dd-function)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel foreach only returns first value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19906515/laravel-foreach-only-returns-first-value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation for [dd()](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/helpers#method-dd) it "*dumps the given variables and ends execution of the script*" - the important part is "*ends execution of the script*"!

If you don't want to end execution use [dump()](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/helpers#method-dump) instead of `dd()`

Comment: Please hammer this duplicate closed.